# convert a firebase QuerySnapshot variable into a list, to perform operations on the data in Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am working in Kotlin with a list of data  but I cannot extract an integer data type to do calculations, I want to convert the list  into a Mutable list, to work better.

thanks for your help

```
data class Task(val value:Int, val Concept:String) {

}

val tasksnew = mutableListOf<Task>()
val docRef = db.collection("requisiciones")
.get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        for (num in document){
           Log.i("yefer", "${num.data["value"]}")
            val valor:String = num.get("value").toString()
            val valorInt :Int = valor.toInt()
            Log.i("yefer", "vamos por mas ${valorInt.toString()}")
            tasksnew.add(valorInt,num.data["concept"].toString())}
```

I still can't add the data to the `taskNew` variable.

Comment: What do you mean by you can’t?  Your code above looks like it does what you described.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're trying to use `tasksnew` {**outside** of the success listener, at which point it won't have been populated yet.

---

All data is loaded from Firestore (like pretty much any modern cloud API) asynchronously, since it may take some time before it's available. Rather than blocking the app (and user) while the data is loaded, your main code continues to run - and then when the data is available, your success listener is called.

There is no way to change this order, so you'll need to make sure all code that needs the data is inside the success callback, is called from there, or is otherwise synchronized.

---

This is an incredibly common source of confusion, so I recommend checking out:

- [Why does my function that calls an API or launches a coroutine return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o/57330767#57330767)
- [How to use kotlin coroutines with for a firestore query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67787050/how-to-use-kotlin-coroutines-with-for-a-firestore-query/68113342#68113342)
- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)
- [How to return a list from Firestore database as a result of a function in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/51595202#51595202)